# jQuery - Animate a div on hover, reset using animation once mouseoff

Tags: jquery, html, animation

I'm trying to animate a `div`, `#blackcrownlinksb`, when I hover over another `div`, `#blackcrownlink`. I want `#blackcrownlinksb` to become `opacity:1`; when hovered over, and return to `opacity:0`; when the mouse leaves it.

So far I have:

```
$('#blackcrownlink').hover(function() {
$('#blackcrownlinksb').animate({
 opacity: 1,
 }, 600);
});
```

which makes `#blackcrownsb` appear. However, I cannot seem to get the syntax right for the second half of this script.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Why you don't try it with css ?

#blackcrownlink:hover #blackcrownlinksb {
opacity: 1;
}

Comment: Yeah.. I'm not seeing why you need to use JS to do this?

Comment: I suppose I could add it with css, but I am trying to learn jQuery and my css is already quite big for this page! Thank you for the suggestion though; I was trying to work out the best way to do it in CSS as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function [`.hover(mouseenter, mouseleave)`](https://api.jquery.com/hover/) lets you specify the enter and leave functions. You can just put a comma and add the function as a 2nd parameter:

```
$('#blackcrownlink').hover(function() {
    $('#blackcrownlinksb').stop().animate({
        opacity: 1,
    }, 600);
}, function() {
    // If you want it to Animate
    $('#blackcrownlinksb').stop().animate({
        opacity: 0,
    }, 600);

    //// If you want to instantly Set it
    //$('#blackcrownlinksb').css("opacity", 0);
});
```

I also added [`.stop()`](https://api.jquery.com/stop/) so that mousing over/out will react instantly.

Comment: Thank you, perfect answer. I knew that there was a way to add the `.animate` as a second parameter, but I was getting my }s and )s mixed up and miscounted. Thank you for laying it out well.